# DNS Leak with VPNBook (OpenVPN)

Tags: vpn, ubuntu, openvpn

**DNS Leak with VPNBook (OpenVPN)**

**My current setup:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 17.04

Service: OpenVPN

VPN: VPNBook (free)
```

**VPN Setup:**

I setup VPNBook on my Ubuntu OS by downloading the US1 Files on this link:

https://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn

Then I used the terminal to navigate to the folder and I ran this command to start the service:

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn
```

After that, I entered the username and password and it proceeded to finish the setup. Once it Finished, I checked my IP with this site:

https://www.dnsleaktest.com/

My IP Addresses was hidden, but when I ran the standard test, it was still showing my ISP name for the DNS Leak. How can I change the DNS to OpenDNS Addresses (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) while using VPNBook? I checked the file located at `/etc/resolv.conf` but I get this message:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

It sais any changes will be overwriten, so how can I still change the DNS to OpenDNS to preven any further leaks while using VPNBook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the DNS servers to use in your OpenVPN client configuration.

So for OpenDNS it would be the following:

```
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222
dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: Would I add that into the /etc/resolv.conf file?

Comment: You need to add it to your OpenVPN client configuration. In your case it would be vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn

Comment: That's what I mean. I don't know how to view or change the configuration file. When I run openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn it just asks for username and password, nothing about dhcp-option

Comment: Have you edited the .ovpn file in a text editor and added the dhcp-option lines? It should look like this https://pastebin.com/gSvKjRzD

Comment: Hmm, perhaps resolved is keeping your ISP DNS server. You should be able to check with `systemd-resolve --status`. It's a bit of a hack but you could just stop resovled and edit resolve.conf with the DNS servers you want.

Comment: Im not sure what it was, but it started working now. I restarted my computer and after setting it all up again it worked. Sorry for not following up in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux, you would have to change your resolv file on the fly. You can invoke a script when the VPN goes up or down to take care of that.

Here is a link that describes the process: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-i-think-i-solved-dns-leakage-on-my-centos-7-pc-4175602864/

And for Ubuntu specifically: [How To Fix OpenVPN DNS Leak in Linux](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html)

Verify that your /etc/resolv.conf has changed after launching Openvpn and is restored when Openvpn terminates.

Comment: I don't think that only resolv.conf can provide dns server information. for example /etc/system/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 has dnsserver param. under linux you could use https://github.com/macvk/dnsleaktest or other tool to detect real dns servers.